# Clang's AST parser treats unknown type name as int

Tags: c++, c, parsing, clang

I tried to use clang's ParseAST() and ASTConsumer to extract all c function declarations in a source file, and then output these function declarations into another file.

It's all good unless there is some unknown type name exists. For example,

```
my_type foo(int x) { /*...*/ }    // "my_type" is just a type identifier whose definition is missed in this translation unit.
```

When I use getReturnType() in RecursiveASTVisitor::VisitFunctionDecl(), it will return type "int". So my program will output

```
int foo(int x);
```

instead of

```
my_type foo(int x);
```

I'm curious why `"my_type"` will be parsed as of type `int`.
When parsing this source code, clang will report an error saying error:

> unknown type name 'my_type'

. So I think clang knows it's a type (unknown type is also a type I think).

Comment: Maybe the parser assumes that `foo` hasn't been declared if the declaration is invalid (because of the unknown return type)? In this case, `foo` is an undeclared function which takes arbitrary arguments (as with an unprototyped function) and returns an `int`.

Comment: Are you including the definition of `my_type` in the code you are letting clang parse?

Comment: @MortenJensen: I don't want to include the definition of my_type. Just want to leave it an unknown type. My point is that, since the parser knows it's indeed a type, although "unknown", wouldn't it be better to leave it as it is?

Comment: @waiwai444 I see where you are going, but remember the Clang Parser was probably built for parsing building programs out of valid C in the first place, and for static analysis secondly. My guess is it stems from the C standard: `The default return value from a function is int. In other words, unless explicitly specified the default return value by compiler would be integer value from function.` - So when you're omitting the definition of `my_type` it defaults to `int`.

Comment: @MortenJensen: You are right. But I think it's about the semantics, not syntax. But if clang's AST is designed like this and there is no way to change this feature, I have no choice but to find other tools to achieve my goal, maybe using lex and yacc to generate my own AST. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, all unknown types are replaced by "int", not only the return type.

Comment: @waiwai444 I can recommend Eli Bendersky's `pycparser` - check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250702/build-ast-from-c-code/20251060 in which I've given a few recommendations